# exec vs import, why errors only in one of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded the code from here https://github.com/SpaceNetChallenge/SpaceNet_SAR_Buildings_Solutions, specifically using model 1. I downloaded the weights corresponding and created the following file to load the model and test. First, I copy the Unet part in `main.py` into a separate file `umodel.py` and the test file as follows

```
import torch
exec(open("./umodel.py").read())
network_data = torch.load('snapshot_fold_8_best')

print(network_data.keys())
import sys
sys.path.append("geffnet")



class Namespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
args = Namespace(extra_num = 1,
                 dec_ch =  [32, 64, 128, 256, 1024],
                 stride=32,
                 net='b5',
                 bot1x1=True,
                 glob=True,
                 bn=True,
                 aspp=True,
                 ocr=True,
                 aux_scale=True)

def load_state_dict(model, state_dict):
    missing_keys = []
    


# from UnetOS.umodel import Unet
exec(open("./umodel.py").read())
try:
    from torch.hub import load_state_dict_from_url
except ImportError:
    from torch.utils.model_zoo import load_url as load_state_dict_from_url

# from UnetOS.umodel import *

model = Unet(extra_num = args.extra_num, dec_ch = args.dec_ch, stride=args.stride, net=args.net, bot1x1 = args.bot1x1, glob=args.glob, bn=args.bn, aspp=args.aspp,
        ocr=args.ocr, aux = args.aux_scale > 0).cuda()

load_state_dict(model, network_data)
```

My question is, why `exec(open("./umodel.py").read())` works nicely but whenever I tried to import `from umodel import Unet` it has errors

```js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10492/1282530406.py in <module>
      9 # ah
     10 model = Unet(extra_num = args.extra_num, dec_ch = args.dec_ch, stride=args.stride, net=args.net, bot1x1 = args.bot1x1, glob=args.glob, bn=args.bn, aspp=args.aspp,
---> 11         ocr=args.ocr, aux = args.aux_scale > 0).cuda()
     12 #model = Unet()
     13 #print(network_data.key())

D:\hines\Pretrained\1-zbigniewwojna\UnetOS\umodel.py in __init__(self, extra_num, dec_ch, stride, net, bot1x1, glob, bn, aspp, ocr, aux)
    238             ['ir_r4_k5_s2_e6_c192_se0.25'],
    239             ['ir_r1_k3_s1_e6_c320_se0.25']]
--> 240         enc = GenEfficientNet(in_chans=3, block_args=decode_arch_def(arch_def, depth_multiplier),
    241                               num_features=round_channels(1280, channel_multiplier, 8, None), stem_size=32,
    242                               channel_multiplier=channel_multiplier, act_layer=resolve_act_layer({}, 'swish'),

NameError: name 'decode_arch_def' is not defined
```

The main file is as follow https://github.com/SpaceNetChallenge/SpaceNet_SAR_Buildings_Solutions/blob/master/1-zbigniewwojna/main.py

Comment: *"it has errors"* - What is the *exact* error message that you get?

Comment: What errors? Please [edit] to include them in the question, and please try to make a [mre].

Comment: "I copy the Unet part in main.py" - what exactly do you copy into a new file? Just the class definition?

Comment: @Grisma I copy the class Unet in the main file, attached above.

Comment: I voted to reopen because the additions by OP make the problem clear - there's an import/scoping issue, I think the answer below solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it appears that `decode_arch_def` is not available and looking at your imports, that has to come from `from geffnet.efficientnet_builder import *` (it does https://github.com/rwightman/gen-efficientnet-pytorch/blob/master/geffnet/efficientnet_builder.py)

Your `exec` must have worked because it followed a similar import, that brought `decode_arch_def` in scope - `exec()` executes code in the current scope, so it will work because in that scope `decode_arch_def` is already defined.

However, when you import, the imported module itself doesn't have the function you need in scope. You should add the required `import` statements to the file you're importing to bring them into scope and it should work.

For example, with a `mod.py` containing this:

```
def my_func():
    print(datetime.now())
```

This works:

```
from datetime import datetime

exec(open("./mod.py").read())
my_func()
```

But this does not:

```
from datetime import datetime
import mod

mod.my_func()
```

To make that work, `mod.py` would have to be:

```
from datetime import datetime

def my_func():
    print(datetime.now())
```

And the import of `datetime` wouldn't be needed in the main program, since it's not referenced there. Your code has a similar issue - you need to determine all the dependencies of your `Unet` class and import them.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense!